# Implementing 'Sign in with Google' feature on Angular app with Passport.js

Tags: angularjs, passport.js, mean-stack

How do I implement a 'sign in with Google' feature on an Angular (MEAN stack) web app? Once I click 'Allow' on the Google sign in page, the page is unable to redirect to my site, instead it just stalls.

This is what I have in my app.js file:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
.
.
.
passport.use('google', new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: "[my client id].apps.googleusercontent.com",
        clientSecret: "[my clientSecret]",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
    },
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
          return cb(err, user);
        });
      }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: [
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'] 
}));

app.get( '/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));
```

Comment: What exactly have you found unclear? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: added some details to the question